# Push local commit

Tags: git, push, commit

I have checked out on my last commit, (git checkout asd94e),than have changed some files and  commited changing, so as I can not push wihout selecting branch, I have checked out on my abc branch but I can not see my commit and do push. Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: another branch will not have the same modifications you made in your old branch unless you merge them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but this sounds like a "lost commit" type of question--maybe your commit was a branch-less HEAD, you checked out the actual branch to push, then "lost" your commit? Search for "lost commit".  The good news is, local commits are only ever temporarily "lost" with Git.

Comment: The command `git checkout asd94e` puts the repo in the [*"detached `HEAD`"*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) status. You should not put the repo in this status unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem..

I have got all my commit history by `git reflog`, than have checked out to my commit by `git reset --hard <commitid>` , than have checked out on my branch and have push all changes

Thanks!